# Detect added packages in CI/CD pipeline using docker and GitLab

Tags: r, docker, gitlab, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

i am currently working on deploying an R application via a CI/CD pipeline. Right now i have an DockerfileBase, which builds to an image containing all the R libraries needed for the project. Now i want to somehow integrate the functionality that somehow it is detected when a library is added to the DockerfileBase and only then this image is rebuild. Does anybody have an idea on how to do a thing like that?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: How do you add the library? Is it a new file/directory in your git repository?

Comment: I want to be able to add an library in the dockerfile like : 
install.packages(c('yaml','shiny','shinydashboard','dplyr'))
And after pushing the dockerfile to my repo it should automatically rebuild the docker image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a job when a specific file (or files) has changes, we can use the [`rule:changes`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges) keyword:

```yaml
Build Docker Image:
  stage: build
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
      changes:
        - Dockerfile
      when: on_success
  script:
    - ./docker_build_script.sh # just an example that represents the steps you run in the job
```

Let's walk through the `rules` syntax:

1. First we check if the `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` [Predefined Variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) is "push". This can be any of the other values for this variable as defined in the docs, or you can skip it entirely:

```yaml
rules:
  changes: 
    - Dockerfile
  when: on_success
```

2. The `changes` syntax in a rule means "evaluate as `true` if the file or files in the array have changes" in the latest commit.
3. The `when: on_success` means "only run this job if all previous jobs passed successfully". This can also be `when: manual`, `when: always`, or left off entirely as the default is `on_success`. If our one rule does not evaluate as `true`, it equates to `when: never` so the job doesn't run.
4. The `script` section stays the same as you use it currently.